# Adding Kernel to a disk image without 'installing'

Tags: kernel

In order to download a disk image from my Ubuntu 10.04 LTS based VPS, I setup Ubuntu 14.04 LTS (in VirtualBox) and used DD over SSH. I wrote the image to a vdi drive, hoping to be able to boot it in another VM.
To my surprise, the image I downloaded does not contain a kernel. (Seems my VPS host boots the kernel externally to my installed OS.)

I have the Ubuntu 10.04 LTS file system mounted in my Ubuntu 14.04 install (/mnt/tmp) and wish to 'place' all the kernel software onto it without having to install (since 14.04 is the running OS).

[Added]
What I'm thinking of doing is to install Ubuntu 10.04 LTS in another VM, then mount the drive on the Ubuntu 14.04 VM alongside the VPS image I downloaded.  I would then copy all the files from the downloaded image on to the Ubuntu 10.04 drive, after which I would revert back to the Ubuntu 10.04 VM (and hope it worked).

Another option would be to create a Ubuntu 10.04 VM with two drives ( / and /BOOT).  Then replace the / drive with the image I downloaded. [/Added]

Any advice on how to achieve this?

Cheers,
Nap